# How to post a comment on a pull request if changes is made to a certain class

Tags: java, github-actions

Hey there id like to make a github workflow that will add a comment to a pullrequest if changes are made to classes who extend the object 'NonPermissive'.
Ive unfortunately been unsuccessful in finding a proper way of doing this and was hoping for some assistance.

Comment: What did you try? There are different options to achieve what you want. A [paths](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore) subtype for pull_request could help you detect those changes when opening the PR, or even [paths-filter actions](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter). Then you could just generate a comment on the PR through the GitHub CLI, API or an action.